# SASS and importing into one stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I am a bit conflicted on whether to have seperate .scss/css files for things like header, homepage, about page

Then on the other side having them all imported into one global.scss file.

In terms of fixing the issue through the DOM, you then have to then find out what line of css it is on, then go to the relevant scss file to change it and correct the problem.

So my question is, what is the best practice. I understand that compiling into one css file and minifying it is best practice but in terms of debugging I would think that having separate scss/css files would prove to be the better option?

Thanks for any advice or experience

Comment: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sass compiler has the option to generate a .map file which maps your css to the lines of code in your sass file while debugging (using inspect element e.t.c).

There is not really a best practice universally , as there are many factors to consider such as compiling sass libraries (susy/bootstrap), or collaboration between multiple developers.

At the end of the day though it really comes down to what works best for you.

Comment: Cool, will just have to read up on how to make a .map file correctly. Think someone above linked a method of doing so :)

Comment: This is usally an automatic process if you are using something like grunt or gulp

Comment: Yea I am using compass so i put

sass_options = {:sourcemap => true}

Into my config.rb to do it for me :) Thanks for the advice!